# Is UIViewControllerContextTransitioning's containerView really "the view that contains both views involved in the transition"?

Tags: ios, animation

I'm presenting a VC modally using a segue with an "over fullscreen" presentation, which means neither view will get removed from the hierarchy after the transition. Let's call the controllers `fromViewController` and `toViewController`.

In my `animateTransition` function the description of the `transitionContext.containerView()` is

> The view that acts as the superview for the views involved in the
>   transition. The view that contains both views involved in the
>   transition.
>
> Returns   The view that contains both views involved in the
>   transition

I decided to test this:

When I **don't** use my custom transition (just the built-in crossfade) and inspect the view hierarchy at runtime, the container view is an instance of `UITransitionView` and does not contain the `fromViewController`--instead it is its sibling. The description of the containerView doesn't seem accurate in that case, and of course the built-in transition *might* use different logic.

When I **do** use my custom transition, both presentation and dismissal works if I only do `containerView?.addSubview(toViewController.view)`. But as soon as I also do `containerView?.addSubview(fromViewController.view)` the dismissal of the `toViewController` will break, and I end up with an empty UIWindow.

I.e. something like this:

```
class MyAnimationController : NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning 
{

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey),
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey) else { return }

    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
    // containerView?.addSubview(fromViewController) // breaks dismissal
    containerView?.addSubview(toViewController)

    }
    // ...
}
```

I'm wondering what "The view that contains both views involved in the transition" means here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that it contains them. But the details depend on the presentation style, and in any case it doesn't mean that you *add both* of them. The "from" view is not yours to add; it is, in effect, not yours (because in a modal presentation transition, it doesn't move). It is the runtime's job to add it. My book explains in detail:

> What the runtime must do while a view is being presented in order to make the presentation customizable is also more complex. There is no existing view to serve as the container view; therefore, when the presentation starts, the runtime must construct the container view and insert it into the interface and leave it there for only as long as the view remains presented. In the case of a `.FullScreen` presentation, the runtime must also rip the presenting view out of the interface and insert it into the container view, because you might want the presenting view to participate in the animation. For other styles of presentation, the container view is *in front of* the presenting view, which can't be animated and is left in place as the presentation proceeds.

If this were, say, a navigation transition, then you *still* would not "add" the from view, as it is already there, but you would be free to move the from view as part of the animation.

Comment: Well it obviously *doesn't* contain them :) I'm interpreting your answer as "the view that sometimes contains the from-view, and to which you are meant to have added the to-view by the end of the transition". It is still unclear from what I found in the docs when I'm allowed to animate the from-view.